# shell_exec() Does Not Work Used in Admin Panel of WordPress

Tags: php, xampp, background-process, wordpress

I'm using `shell_exec()` to run a background process in my WordPress plugin and found that WordPress somehow gets confused when `shell_exec()` is used in an Admin option page. It seems that inclusion using relative paths do not process correctly.

This is the sample plugin I wrote to demonstrate the problem:

```
/* Plugin Name: Sample ShellExec */

add_action('admin_menu', 'sample_shellexec_menu');
function sample_shellexec_menu() {
    add_options_page(
        'Sample Shell Exec', 
        'Sample Shell Exec', 
        'manage_options',
        'sample_shell_exec', 
        'sample_shellexec_admin');
}
function sample_shellexec_admin() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
    <?php
        $phppath = 'php';
        // $phppath = 'Z:\xampp\php\php.exe'; // in my case
        echo ABSPATH . '<br />';
        $output = shell_exec($phppath . ' "' . ABSPATH . '/index.php" 2>&1');       
        echo $output;
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Go to the option page and you'll see an error message like,

> Warning: require(./wp-blog-header.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in *[path to the WordPress]*\index.php on line 17 Call
>   Stack: 0.0002 320664 1. {main}() *[path to the WordPress]*\index.php:0
>   Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required './wp-blog-header.php'
>   (include_path='.;\xampp\php\PEAR') in *[path to the WordPress]*\index.php
>   on line 17 Call Stack: 0.0002 320664 1. {main}()
>   *[path to the WordPress]*\index.php:0

The error does not occur if `shell_exec()` is used outside the admin panel. I'd like to know why.

Comment: `var_dump()` the string given to `shell_exec()` what's could be wrong. What's inside `ABSPATH`?

Comment: As you see in the example code I provided above, I used `echo()` to see the value of `ABSPATH` and the output of `shell_exec()`. I tried `var_dump()` as well but it returned the same result as `echo()`. The output value of `ABSPATH` shows the WordPress installed path correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to force the environnement to run your command in the good path:

```
shell_exec("cd " . escapeshellarg(ABSPATH) . "; " . $phppath . ' index.php 2>&1');
```

I'm used to Linux systems so I don't know if this works on Window.

Comment: The output gives `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.` Does it work on your server?

Comment: unfortulately yes, i'll try to find the same approach for windows

Comment: try to replace the `;` by a `&` : found the answer [here](http://htipe.wordpress.com/2009/07/19/multiple-commands-on-a-single-windows-command-line/)

Comment: Wao, worked! Thanks. I'd like to know why the directory needs to be changed when used in the admin panel.

Comment: Because the admin panel is not in the same directory as other files (ie: index which is used for all normal routing is in the root directory, but wp-admin is a separated directory). And if you try to exec() something from a directory, your new instance will have the [get_include_path()](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.get-include-path.php) of where it has been executed.

Comment: I see, I didn't know such an important thing. Thanks for the explanation.